# SUM operation on SET data type returns incorrect result

Tags: mysql, types, aggregate-functions

I am getting wrong output for **`SUM()`** operation when applied on a **`SET`** data type.

The table with set data type:

```
CREATE TABLE rating(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `prodId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `starRating` set('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table records are as follows:

```
| ID | prodId | starRating |
| 1  |   1    |    1       |
| 2  |   2    |    2       |
| 3  |   3    |    3       |
| 4  |   4    |    4       |
| 5  |   5    |    5       |
```

Finally, my query is like:

```
SELECT `prodId`, SUM(`starRating`) FROM `rating`
GROUP BY `prodId`
```

And the output is:

```
| prodId | SUM(starRating) |
|   1    |    1            |
|   2    |    2            |
|   3    |    4            |
|   4    |    8            |
|   5    |    16           |
```

Output for product ID 4 and 5 is wrong as its rating should be 4 and 5 respectively.

Moreover, it takes rating 3 as 4, 4 as 8 and 5 as 16 individually every time we calculate them with `SUM()` function. I am unable to find out that Where I am doing mistake?

Comment: Everything seems ok here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d61ab/1. What is the exact content of your table rating at the moment ?

Comment: Have you try `CAST`? `SUM(CAST(starRating AS int))`

Comment: Don't use the SET data type

Comment: @Romeo Nivo: Yes tried, but no change found.

Comment: @Gosfly: I've provided in the question. That is the exact table records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using MySQL 8+ the correct datatype would be:

```
starRating int NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CHECK (starRating BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
```

The [`SET` datatype](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set.html) does not work the way you expect. You could use tricks to extract the string value then use it inside numeric context:

```
select prodId, avg(concat(starRating, '')) AS avg_rating
from rating
group by prodId
```

Comment: +0 seems simpler

Comment: Yes, its doing the correct calculation with SUM() function also. But still there is a confusion, why it behaves like this??

Comment: @rohit that would be too long for a comment but to summarize: the set values '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'... are mapped to numbers 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... behind the scene. MySQL will use those numbers when the column is used in numeric context (`SELECT starRating + 0` returns 4 for `'3'`). If you do `INSERT INTO t(starRating) VALUES (4)` it'll actually insert `'3'`.

Comment: @Strawberry `+0` would simply produce the same result as described in OP e.g. '5' becomes 16.

Answer (score 0):

In your case statement `starRating` is a `CHAR` type so you need CAST the to integer `SIGNED   Converts value to SIGNED (a signed 64-bit integer)`.
It would look like -

```
SELECT `prodId`, SUM(`starRating` AS SIGNED) FROM `rating`GROUP BY `prodId`
```